# Best way to clean http part of URL

Tags: python

I'm looking for a simple way to clean URLs as follows:

- `https://` replaced with `http://`
- URLs missing `http(s)` prefix, example: `://` should have it appended.

Is there a way to do this out of the box with python? Example:

`https://example.com/path/` -> `http://example.com/path/`

`://example.com/path/` -> `http://example.com/path/`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a regex?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard python library [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this.

```
import re

# match strings that start with either 'http://' or '://'
pattern = r'^(https://|://)' 

# replace matches with 'http://'
repl = 'http://'

test1 = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
result1 = re.sub(pattern, repl, test1, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
# result1 == 'http://stackoverflow.com'

test2 = '://stackoverflow.com'
result2 = re.sub(pattern, repl, test2, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
# result2 == 'http://stackoverflow.com'
```

Using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with the flag `re.IGNORECASE` will let you handle any case variations of `https://` prefixes without having to convert a URL to lowercase and maybe destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def format_url(url): 
    if url.startswith('https'):
        url = 'http:' + url.split(':')[1]
    elif url.startswith(':'):
        url = 'http' + url
    return url
```

**Output:**

```
>>> format_url('https://example.com/path/')
'http://example.com/path/'
>>> format_url('://example.com/path/')
'http://example.com/path/'
```

Comment: Would just this line be suffice for both scenarios?
`url = 'http:' + url.split(':')[1]`

Answer (score -1):

Well there is a multitude of ways to doing this, some involving strings and others involving combining different strings, so I'll give you both.

Using str.replace():

```
url = 'https://www.python.org'
url.replace('https', 'http')
print url
```

Adding pieces together (this idea was used earlier but might as well repeat it)

```
if url.startswith('https://):
    url = 'http://' + rest_of_address
```

This works by detecting if the string starts with https, and then replaces it with http if its true.  If you wanted to add another parameter you could use url.endswith or use 'if foo in url:' and there you go.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'example.com/path/');
    exit;
?>
```

or somethnig like that...Note that its an php script....(.php file and php server is needed)

Comment: This is a [tag:python] question.